# xmpphp XMPP, send message from php script

Tags: php, real-time, xmpp, xmpphp

Hi
I have a jabberserver and i would like to be able to push messages out to users from a php script.

F.x. if i call script.php from my browser, it sends a message to a user.
I've tried both with jaxl and xmpphp which are xmp frameworks, but i cant get it to work. Not with my own server, and neither with facebooks server.

I have the following ind my script.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);    
include("lib/xmpphp/XMPPHP.php");  
$conn = new XMPP('chat.facebook.dk', 5222, 'username', 'password', '', 'chat.facebook.com', true, XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);  
$conn->connect();  
$conn->processUntil('session_start');  
$conn->message('someusername@chat.facebook.com', 'This is a test message!');  
$conn->disconnect();
```

But nothing happends and no errors either.
I've followed this guide to set up an echobot, and it works with both my server and facebook. The script is here: http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2010/02/writing-your-first-facebook-chat-bot-in-php-using-jaxl-library/ <-- and is run on the server commandline, and waiting for a message, and then replys.

What do i have to do ?

Comment: what server if your script running on ? windows / unix ? Check if the mail is working.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the mail is correct.

Comment: I meant mailer deamon (SMTP server)

Comment: Uhm, the emails doesnt exists? its usernames. I'm not trying to send emails, but messages to a jabber user.

Comment: Is someusername@chat.facebook.com in your connected user roster list. If someusername is not in ur roster, he will never receive ur message, though Jaxl logs will show message was dispatched successfully.

Comment: Abhinav's comment should be in an answer not a comment, so this post can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
set_time_limit(0);  // some time connection take while  
require_once 'xmpp-lib/XMPPHP/XMPP.php';  
$host = 'you Host name'; // ex.192.168.2.1  
$port = '5222'; // its defauls xmpp port 
$username = 'name@host' // ex vivek@host 
$pass = 'userpass';  
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP(host , $port, $username, $pass, 'xmpphp','yourhost', $printlog=false, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);  
try {
         $conn->connect();
         $conn->processUntil('session_start');
         $conn->presence();
         $conn->message('anotherusername@host', 'Hello!');
         $conn->disconnect(); 
} catch(XMPPHP_Exception $e) {
         die($e->getMessage()); 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$command = 'send_message';
$requestParams = array('type' => 'chat',
    'to' => '919999999999@127.0.0.0',
    'from' => '919999999991@127.0.0.0',
    'body' => 'Hi vivek patel',
    'subject' => 'test',
);

$request = xmlrpc_encode_request($command, $requestParams, (array('encoding' => 'utf-8')));
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => "POST",
        'header' => "User-Agent: XMLRPC::Client mod_xmlrpc\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n" .
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($request),
        'content' => $request
    )
        )
);
try {
    $file = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.0:4560/RPC2", false, $context);
    $response = xmlrpc_decode($file);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (xmlrpc_is_fault($response)) {
    trigger_error("xmlrpc: $response[faultString] ($response[faultCode])");
}
echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: please can you give some more details about what is doing this piece of code and what was wrong in the original question

Comment: @sancelot the piece of code for send message jid 1 to jid2 from jabber server use of PHP script with XMLRPC. about the original question send message from PHP script xmlrpc is easiest way.