# receive XMPP message with php

Tags: php, iphone, xmpp

I have PHP+mysql and XMPP server on the same machine, I don't know if it's possible to do this: 
when client@xmpp sends a message "hello" to PHP@xmpp (e.g. from iPhone), a PHP script on the XMPP server will be automatically called and all variables will be passed over, so that the PHP script can insert this message to mysql.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

Look at the API in XMPPHP library

http://code.google.com/p/xmpphp/

there are tons of questions here about the same

[xmpphp XMPP, send message from php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680930/xmpphp-xmpp-send-message-from-php-script)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-alertxmpptut/section4.html

Comment: sorry man, but what I ask is "receiving xmpp msg" instead of "sending xmpp msg". in other words, I need xmpp server to call a php script when a message is received. is it possible? thanks

Comment: Hi meditic i have also the same problem i have send the message using php and xmpp but i am not able to receive the message.